# PHP number_format() and round() not producing valid upper-range results 3

Tags: php

**CODE:**

```
in_array($number, round(range(65,74)))
```

or

```
round(in_array($number,range(65,74)))
```

I'm doing a switch case whenever the user inputs `73.4` the result is `null`. But whenever I input `73` or `74` it executes.

How to do it I'm a newbie in php here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to round the user input number and not the range. So, it will be ,

```
in_array(round($number), range(65,74));
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/XtihDBhG).